# Thread stops randomly without an error

Tags: java, multithreading

So basically i'm learning about threads at the minute so i'm not 100% sure on them but i have created two producers and two consumers and they were working fine but I've changed something and now their not?

```
public class SingleBufferMonitor {

    private int buffer;
    private boolean full;

    public SingleBufferMonitor(){
        full = false;
    }

    public synchronized int get(){
        while(full == false) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
            notify();
            full = false;
            return buffer;

    }//get

    public synchronized void put(int value){
        while(full == true){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        buffer = value;
        full = true;
        notify();
    }//put
}
```

}

```
public class ConsumerThread extends Thread {

    private int aValue;
    private SingleBufferMonitor sharedBuffer;
    //private Random rand = new Random();

    public ConsumerThread(SingleBufferMonitor buffer, String name){
        super(name);
        sharedBuffer = buffer;
    }

    public void run(){
        String entrant;

        for(int count=1; count < 10; count++){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                aValue = sharedBuffer.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(count == 1){
                entrant = "person";
            }
            else{
                entrant = "people";
            }

            System.out.println(getName() + aValue + " " + entrant +" left");
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class ProducerThread extends Thread {

    private SingleBufferMonitor sharedBuffer;
    private Random rand = new Random();
    public long startTime, endTime, timeTaken, averageTime;


    public ProducerThread(SingleBufferMonitor buffer, String name){
        super(name);
        sharedBuffer = buffer;
    }

    public void run(){
        int tSleep = rand.nextInt(1000);
        String entrant;
        int count;

        for(count = 1; count < 10; count++){
            try {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Thread.sleep(tSleep);
                sharedBuffer.put(count);
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                timeTaken = endTime - startTime;
                averageTime = averageTime + timeTaken;

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(count == 1){
                entrant = "person";
            }
            else{
                entrant = "people";
            }

            System.out.println(getName() + count + " " + entrant +"  came in");
            System.out.println("Time taken for " + count + " " + entrant + " to get into the nightclub: " + timeTaken);
        }
        System.out.println("Average Time taken for " + count + " people to get into the nightclub via entrance 1: " + averageTime);
    }
}
```

}

```
class SingleBufferMonitorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        SingleBufferMonitor box = new SingleBufferMonitor();

        ProducerThread producer1 = new ProducerThread(box, "Entrance 1: ");
        ProducerThread2 producer2 = new ProducerThread2(box, "Entrance 2: ");

        ConsumerThread consumer = new ConsumerThread(box, "Exit 1: ");
        ConsumerThread consumer2 = new ConsumerThread(box, "Exit 2: ");

        producer1.start();
        producer2.start();

        consumer.start();
        consumer2.start();
    }

}
```

Run program once output looks like;
Entrance 1: 1 person  came in
Time taken for 1 person to get into the nightclub: 246
Entrance 1: 2 people  came in
Exit 2: 1 person left
Time taken for 2 people to get into the nightclub: 754
Exit 2: 2 people left

Ran it a second time looks like;
Entrance 2: 1 person  came in
Time taken for 1 person to get into the nightclub: 552
Entrance 1: 1 person  came in
Exit 1: 1 person left
Exit 2: 1 person left
Time taken for 1 person to get into the nightclub: 1000
Entrance 2: 2 people  came in
Time taken for 2 people to get into the nightclub: 552
Entrance 1: 2 people  came in
Exit 2: 2 people left
Time taken for 2 people to get into the nightclub: 1001
Exit 2: 2 people left

etc.etc.

All I can see is that it appears to be the consumer thread causing the problem as it always ends on an "Exit". Also sometimes it makes its way throughout the entire program without stopping and works fine.

Guessing it has something to do with the threads interweaving wrong and both having to wait on nothing? (Just a guess)

P.S. Apologies about the mass of code but I genuinely have no idea whats causing this problem since i'm new to threads so I can't narrow it down.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: In the get() method, you notify() first, and then set the flag value. So you leave a nice little chance for longest waiting thread never seeing the change in flag when you called notify() before setting the flag? Where as your implementation in the put(int) method is fine.

Comment: Tried putting notify beneath full = false but appears to still be doing the same as before.

Comment: Yep and that is exactly why I didn't post it as an answer. Obviously it requires an in-depth detail of the program execution cycle. We are talking multi-threaded programming here :)

Comment: Okay haha is there anything I could add to help? Thanks for the input btw :)

Comment: The problem description is perfectly fine. It's the Producer-Consumer relationship in multi-threaded environment that always brings horror even in the life of the best programmers :D . I am inspecting your problem though

Comment: hahah what have I got myself into in that case. Thanks a lot though ! :)

Comment: Can you try removing the sleep(1000) in the consumer thread code? These threads will block anyway on the get() call... I wonder if you are missing a notify() while sleeping...

Comment: @ShayHaned The `notify()` call and the assignment to `full` are both inside the same `synchronized(...)` block. They effectively happen as an atomic unit as far as the other threads are concerned.

Comment: Don't have time to look into this right now, but I suspect that it's because you are attempting multi-producer/multi-consumer with a single condition variable.  It's better to have one condition variable that's only awated by consumers and signalled by producers, and a second condition variable that's used the other way 'round.  You can't do that using `synchronized` blocks, but you can do it with `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you're not waking up all the threads that are waiting on the implicit monitor in the SingleBufferMonitor object. There are 3 methods that are involved in using a monitor: wait, notify, and ***notifyAll***. notifyAll() will wake up **all** current threads waiting on the monitor. The method you're calling will only wake up a single thread. Since you're only waking up one thread at a time one producer calling put() could wake up the other producer, which would see the buffer as full still and call wait() again. Both consumers are still waiting, and now both producers are waiting, and the program will not progress any further. If you change to using notifyAll() you will see the program finish.

Comment: A better solution would be to use 2 different locks.  One lock for waiting for non-empty and another lock waiting on not-full.